# How to Resolve this issue for handling lower case and upper case with setAccelerator in java

Tags: java, event-listener, keystroke

How can I resolve this issue for handling lowercase and uppercase with `setAccelerator`?

```
mi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_L, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
```

Even if I try like this, java makes no difference between lowercase or uppercase.

```
KeyStroke l = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('l', InputEvent.CTRL_MASK);
mi.setAccelerator(l);
```

Comment: Not sure you can, but you could use `InputEvent.CTRL_MASK | InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK`

Comment: Yeah, but you handle this with 3 keys. My university teacher want this with 2 keys.

Comment: AFAIK you can't differentiate between `L` and `l` in this context, I'm not even sure that add `SHIFT_MASK` would really make that much difference, other then forcing you to press the shift key

Comment: What you suggested working and i'll do that. I don't figure other way so.